# Cost of the government

Tags: finance

I am supposed to solve the following problem.

> The bank provides 1,000 dollars loans. Risk-free clients will repay the loan
>   in full for a year, in addition to paying 4% interest. For a high-risk
>   client, there is a 30% chance that he will not pay anything and an 70%
>   chance that he will repay the loan in full and 30% interest.
>
> Assume that the government has guaranteed to the bank that in the
>   event of non-payment of the loan, it will repay the bank's principal,
>   that means 1,000$.
>
> What costs will the government have?

So I understand that the cost of the government will be 1,000 dollars, but I do not know with what probability. I should calculate the expected cost.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected cost is of $1000\$\times 0.3\times(\text{number of high-risk clients})$ per year.

Comment: I thought that it is complicated, it is really that simple?

Comment: It looks that simple to me.